# Why can't I browse a SQL Server on my Azure virtual network?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-network

I have set up a SQL Server lab on Azure, with a few servers and a Windows 7 client. All are virtual machines sharing the same virtual network, subnet and cloud service.

From the client, I want to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to see the servers on my network. This is an option in the SSMS login screen: Server > 'Browse for more...' When I try to browse, no servers display in the list. Note that I'm able to connect to the servers directly by manually entering the credentials.

[The MSDN site has a page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188200(v=sql.110).aspx) describing things that might prevent you from seeing the servers:

> ... click **Browse for more** in the **Server name** box to open the Browse for Servers dialog box.
>   This dialog is populated by the SQL Server Browser service on the server computers. There are several reasons why the name of an instance might not appear in the list:
>
> - The SQL Server Browser service might not be running on the computer running SQL Server.
> - UDP port 1434 might be blocked by a firewall.
> - The HideInstance flag might be set.

I have enabled the three items in this list, but I'm still coming up short. Ideas?